# trouble in using @PathVariable in spring mvc based application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am bit new with spring framework and I got confused while using `@PathVariable` in my application. The requirement is to access the `categoryId` from the `url pattern`. This is what I written in `jsp` :

```
<a href="cat/1">Categories</a>
```

And when it will be clicked i want to collect the categoryId from the url, this is what I have written in Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/cat/{categoryId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getCategory(@PathVariable("categoryId") Category categoryId, ModelMap model) {
        System.out.println("Path variable : " + categoryId);
        return "category";
    }
```

Comment: What happens exactly? Does the request reaches to `getCategory` and `categoryId` is null? Or it doesn't even get there?

Comment: Spring cannot convert `1` to a `Category` (or you need to provide a custom converter).

Comment: its not at all calling this method.

Comment: are you sure the paths are correct?

Comment: what path I used is what I mentioned up here.Other then these I used one pojo class with the name Category.java and with one field i.e int caegoryId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So got the problem after screwing up myself. It was not able to bind the categoryId with the pojo class object no matter I take String or int type variable in Category.java pojo class. So finally I changed the parameter type to String in Controller's getCategory() method and it worked. Still don't know why its not able to bind with pojo class object.

Comment: Bits of a path are plain strings, not structured documents. Therefore, their natural mapping is to strings (or possibly other simple types).